# Get all documents in mongo collection that matches any element in the intersection array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to do a lookup in the aggregation but I am having problems in trying to get all documents that match the elements in the array. The goal is to get all the employees that are in the intersection between "$services" and "$$services". These two are arrays of ObjectID's. The lookup will happen in the employee collection. Here is what I tried but did not know how to match after that:

```js
{
            $lookup: {
                from: collection_names.EMPLOYEE,
                let: { services: "$services._id" },
                pipeline: [  
                    {
                        $project: {
                            _id: 0, 
                            intersection: {  $setIntersection: ["$services", "$$services"] },
                        }
                    },
                    // {
                    //     $match: { }
                    // }
                ],
                as: "employees"
            }
        },
```

Here is the full aggregation:

```js
collection.aggregate([
        {
            $geoNear: {
                near: { type: "Point", coordinates: correct_format_loc, },
                key: 'location',
                distanceField: 'location.dist',
                maxDistance: range * 1000,  // 1000 meters
                query: { name: re },
                spherical: true,
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: collection_names.SERVICE,
                let: { business: "$_id" },
                pipeline: [
                    { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$business", "$$business"] } } },
                    {
                        $project: {
                            _id: 1,
                            name: 1,
                            price: 1,
                            category: 1,
                            duration: 1,
                        }
                    } 
                ],
                as: "services"
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: collection_names.EMPLOYEE,
                let: { services: "$services._id" },
                pipeline: [  
                    {
                        $project: {
                            _id: 0, 
                            intersection: {  $setIntersection: ["$services", "$$services"] },
                        }
                    },
                    // {
                    //     $match: { }
                    // }
                ],
                as: "employees"
            }
        },
        { 
            $project: {
                 name: "$name",
                 address: "$address",
                 location: "$location",
                 contact: "$contact",
                 description: "$description",
                 image_paths: "$image_paths",
                 services: '$services',
                 employees: '$employees',
                 rating_avg: {
                     $avg: "$services.rating"
                 }
            }
         },
    ]).toArray()
```

Comment: I think `{ $match: { services: { $in: '$$services' } } }`. *Without* `$project` should do the job. In case `employee.services` already contains array of `_id`s,  otherwise  `{ $match: { "services._id": { $in: '$$services' } } }`

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the solution was having two projections and a match in between. The changes were done in the final `$lookup` in the question I wrote.

What I did was get the intersection and project it as a new property, then match with the expression, and then remove the unnecessary properties that are not needed. Here is how it looks after the changes:

```js
{
            $lookup: {
                from: collection_names.EMPLOYEE,
                let: { services: '$services._id' },
                pipeline: [
                    {
                        $project: {
                            name: 1,
                            description: 1,
                            rating: 1,
                            image_path: 1,
                            services: 1,
                            service_ids: { $setIntersection: ['$services', '$$services'] }
                        }
                    },
                    { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ['$services', '$service_ids'] } } },
                    {
                        $project: {
                            service_ids: 0,
                            services: 0,
                        }
                    }
                ],
                as: "employees"
            }
        },
```